# Setting up VS Code to work with A-Star modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, a-star

I am trying to set up vs code currently to work with my a-star 3.3V module. I have code already working that I have uploaded successfully on the Arduino IDE, but I run into an error (see below). I have done some googling and wasn’t able to find a solution that worked, as most of them involved ensuring the board and ports were configured correctly, but I have already done that (to the best of my knowledge).

[Error] Uploading sketch ‘tuya-a-star.ino’: Exit with code=1

I have included some of the different things below so you can see what I mean, I am hoping I have missed something small here. The correct board and version is also selected as is the correct port. I have also selected the Arduino type for the C/C++ configuration.

arduino.json file

```
{
“configuration”: “version=8mhz”,
“board”: “pololu-a-star:avr:a-star328PB”,
“output”: “…/ArduinoOutput”,
“programmer”: “pololu-a-star:stk500for328PB”,
“sketch”: “tuya-a-star.ino”,
“port”: “COM4”
}
```

Comment: Change the quotes of your JSON file

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. You mean the actual quotation mark symbols are wrong?

Comment: in the code part are smart quotes not `"`

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, there's a strange formatting thing that shows up when the code is pasted here, but the quotes are the correct ones in my editor

Comment: I copy/paste a lot from VSC to SO and never have a smart quote problem, it always is the same ASCII quote